# R : Generate a sequential column based on data from another column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, key, sequence

I have a dataframe 'my_data' which looks like this:

```
Calendar_Day      Name    
2018-03-31        ABC    
2018-03-31        XYZ  
2018-03-31        OPR
2019-01-31        ABC    
2019-01-31        RTE    
2019-10-31        YUD    
2018-03-31        RYT
```

I wish to have another column that will serve as a primary key with a format

```
YEAR+MONTH+6digit sequence  , eg: 201803000001
```

I am new to R and couldn't find a way to implement the concept.

and Dataframe should look like

```
Calendar_Day      Name    ID
2018-03-31        ABC     201803000001
2018-03-31        XYZ     201803000002
2018-03-31        OPR     201803000003
2019-01-31        ABC     201901000001
2019-01-31        RTE     201901000002
2019-10-31        YUD     201910000001
2018-03-31        RYT     201803000004
```

Comment: `ABC`, eg, has different ID's on different days. Is that really what you're after?

Comment: Yes, ABC should have different ID based on year and month also, the last row has 2018-03-31 and it should have ID 4 as dates are not sorted. There are more than 1 million records with dates and names so it might need a fast sort and the assign ID.

Comment: I case of the last component of the id with two digit, you need e.g. 2018120000011 (five zeros) or 2018000010 (four zeros)?

Comment: four zeros is expected in that case, max length of the sequence can be 6 digit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
d %>%
    mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
    group_by(tmp1 = year(Date), tmp2 = month(Date)) %>%
    mutate(ID = paste0(year(Date),
                       sprintf("%02d", month(Date)),
                       sprintf("%05d", row_number()))) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-tmp1, -tmp2)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 3
#>   Date       Name  ID         
#>   <date>     <chr> <chr>      
#> 1 2018-03-31 ABC   20180300001
#> 2 2018-03-31 XYZ   20180300002
#> 3 2018-03-31 OPR   20180300003
#> 4 2019-01-31 ABC   20190100001
#> 5 2019-01-31 RTE   20190100002
#> 6 2019-10-31 YUD   20191000001
#> 7 2018-03-31 RYT   20180300004
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use the tidyverse package like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

mydata  %>%
  mutate(Date2 = format(Date, "%Y%m")) %>%
  group_by(Date2) %>%
  mutate(ID = paste0(Date2, str_pad(1:n(), width = 6, side = "left",  pad = "0"))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-Date2)
```

The main idea is to use the `format` function: `format(mydate, %Y)` returns the year of a date object and `format(mydate, %m)` returns the month of a date object.
I paste these two together and add the six digit sequence.
I use `string_pad` to add leading zeros to the sequence.

Comment: I am getting error : Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `ID` must be length 11595 (the group size) or one, not 413917

Comment: I have 413917 rows in the dataset and each month has around 25000 rows...

Comment: I updated my answer, does it work now?
If not, can you post a part of your data with `dput`